# unity touch actions on android

Tags: android, touch, unity-game-engine

I want to detect when a user has clicked on an object, and also when the user finger is still down on the screen, to check on which object the finger ended.
on click events it would be smoething like this:

```
void OnMouseEnter()
{
    // this is where the finger hovered on
}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    // this is the first touch
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
    // this is where the finger was released from the screen
}
```

so, basiclly I am lloking for `OnMouseEnter()`

thank you

Comment: What type of object is this? Ths UI Image compoent? Sprite Renderer(2D)? Mesh(3D) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay()** to project your touch action position into a ray then use **Raycast** to see whether it hits an object. For example:

```
void Update () {
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) {
        if (Input.GetTouch (i).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.GetTouch(i).position);
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 1000f)) {
                Debug.Log("Touch enter on " + hit.collider.name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are not considering multi-touches, you could also use Mouse input actions. Touch actions will be translated into Mouse actions when built for mobile platforms.

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 1000f)) {
            Debug.Log("Touch enter on " + hit.collider.name);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I think in the end even if you want to use the first version (so that it can handle multi-touch), you will want to implement the second version. Simply because so that you can simulate the touches with your mouse on Editor.

```
void Update () {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
#else
        for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) {
            if (Input.GetTouch (i).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.GetTouch(i).position);
#endif
                RaycastHit hit;
                if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 1000f)) {
                    Debug.Log("Touch enter on " + hit.collider.name);
                }
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
            }
#endif
        }
    }
```

A bit messy though, but something like this should do the trick.

These examples should work for your OnMouseEnter() case. With the same idea you could implement the other responses (for hover and on release/exit).